# Join two lists of lists in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to perform a full outer join between two python_lists. Consider that they both have the same keys: (name and pet). Besides that they have different amounts which both should be shown in the result_list. How do I achieve this in python?

- `list_a = [['John','Cat',10], 
            ['Adam','Dog',20]]`
- `list_b = [['John','Cat',40],
            ['Laura','Fish',60]]`
- `result_list = [['John','Cat',10, 40],
                 ['Adam','Dog',20,0],
                 ['Laura','Fish',0, 60]]]`

Comment: Why does `'John','Cat'` list have 50?

Comment: Are there any ordering guarantees? Are they sorted by pet type, then by name, or are they arbitrarily ordered?

Comment: Writing 50 was a mistake. I have updated to 40. There is no guarantee regarding the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a dictionary in order to do it more efficiently  wrt to an approach that compares each pair of lists.

```
list_a = [['John','Cat',10], ['Adam','Dog',20]]
list_b = [['John','Cat',40], ['Laura','Fish',60]]

d = {}

for person, pet, v in list_a + list_b:
    if (person, pet) in d:
        d[(person, pet)]+=v
    else:
        d[(person, pet)]=v

final_list = [[key[0],key[1],val] for key,val in d.items()]
```

outputs

```
[['John', 'Cat', 50], ['Adam', 'Dog', 20], ['Laura', 'Fish', 60]]
```

**Edit** after having noticed that this is not what OP asked.

For the expected output the code can be changed to be:

```
list_a = [['John','Cat',10], ['Adam','Dog',20]]
list_b = [['John','Cat',40], ['Laura','Fish',60]]

d = dict(((person,pet),[v,0]) for (person,pet,v) in list_a)

for person, pet, v in list_b :
    if (person, pet) in d:
        d[(person, pet)][1] = v
    else:
        d[(person, pet)] = [0,v]


final_list = [[key[0],key[1],val[0],val[1]] for key,val in d.items()]
#python3.x
final_list = [[*key,*val] for key,val in d.items()]
```

which outputs:

```
[['John', 'Cat', 10, 40], ['Adam', 'Dog', 20, 0], ['Laura', 'Fish', 0, 60]]
```

Comment: This doesn't preserve the separation of values by source that the OP seemed to have in mind. The results should have two numbers for each name/pet pair, the value from `list_a` and `list_b` separately (with `0` for missing values in a given `list`), not one that contains the sum of both.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of silly looking, but a straightforward approach is to build it from a `dict` in pieces:

```
d = {}
for name, pettype, val in list_a:
    d[name, pettype] = [val, 0]

for name, pettype, val in list_b:
    try:
        d[name, pettype][1] = val
    except KeyError:
        d[name, pettype] = [0, val]

# Use .items() instead of .viewitems() on Python 3.x
result_list = [[name, pettype, vala, valb] for (name, pettype), (vala, valb) in d.viewitems()]
```

The ordering won't be consistent before Python 3.6; in 3.6 and later, you'll see all the name/pets in order from `list_a`, then those from `list_b` which don't appear in `list_a` in order.

If you really hate repeating yourself, or need to join many such lists, you could tweak it to:

```
d = {}
all_lists = [list_a, list_b, ..., list_n]
for i, curlist in enumerate(all_lists):
    for name, pettype, val in curlist:
        try:
            vals = d[name, pettype]
        except KeyError:
            vals = d[name, pettype] = [0] * len(all_lists)
        vals[i] = val
result_list = [[name, pettype] + vals for (name, pettype), vals in d.viewitems()]
```

or using `collections.defaultdict` to avoid the exception handling code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

all_lists = [list_a, list_b, ..., list_n]
d = defaultdict(lambda: [0] * len(all_lists))
for i, curlist in enumerate(all_lists):
    for name, pettype, val in curlist:
        d[name, pettype][i] = val
result_list = [[name, pettype] + vals for (name, pettype), vals in d.viewitems()]
```